# A word for someone who knows when to ask for help

Tags: single-word-requests

What word could describe someone who knows when to ask for help, or someone who is not afraid to ask for help?

Comment: The context is unclear.  Will this person, after asking for help, actually listen to others suggestions, and will he act on them, or is he just being annoying?

Answer (score 2):

> receptive

It is good for someone who is willing to ask for help, entertain criticism, or engage in new thought.

Answer (score 1):

*[Discerning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discerning)*:

> adjective
>
> Having or showing good judgement:

*[Discerning](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=discern&allowed_in_frame=0)* people **distinguish** their interior world from their exterior world:

> late 14c., from Old French discerner (13c.) "distinguish (between),
>   separate" (by sifting), and directly from Latin discernere "to
>   separate, set apart, divide, distribute; distinguish, perceive,"
>   from dis- "off, away" (see dis-) + cernere "distinguish, separate,
>   sift" (see *[crisis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crisis&allowed_in_frame=0)*).

When faced with a crisis of personal inadequacy, discerning people ask for help.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of discerning people who are still reluctant to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call that person ***reasonable***

> *Joe is quite a **reasonable** fellow; he'll ask for help as soon as he needs it.*

Merriam Webster defines it as:

> having the faculty of reason.
>   possessing sound judgement

Comment: This isn't very specific to the quality in the question. Notice that you had to add the second clause to indicate that you're talking about asking for help. Without that, there's a wide spectrum of ways that he may be reasonable, which might not even include asking for help.

Comment: @Barmar - you are right.  But I don't know any words mean exactly "help-seeker" and if I were trying to describe such a person to someone, I'd likely use the wording I proposed.

Comment: There's a difference between a word you can use to describe people who have a quality, and a word which actually refers to the quality. E.g. most basketball players are tall, but that isn't a word for basketball players.

Comment: @Barmar- right again.  Note that the OP asks for a word to *describe* some who is willing to ask for help when they need it. **not**, a word that *means* a person who is willing to ask for help when they need it.

Comment: That's a pet peave of mine. I'm of the opinion that when someone asks a question like this, they're asking for a word that refers to the category; notice his title. It doesn't seem likely to me that they could really use a word that merely describes members of the group, and I think people who answer that question are being overly literal. I know this is a language site, but that doesn't mean that questioners will necessarily use the perfect language to express their requests, and common sense should be used to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If said person asks respectfully, she may be labeled a **supplicant**. There is a connotation of reverence there.

Answer (score 0):

**humble** (hŭm′bəl) adj. -[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/humble)

> 1. Marked by meekness or modesty in behavior, attitude, or spirit; **not arrogant or prideful**.

*[Only the penitent man shall pass...](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20penitent%20man%20kneels%20before%20god&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=indiana%20jones%20only%20the%20penitent%20man%20shall%20pass&spell=1)*